# the blood test riddle (number theory)

Tags: number-theory, puzzle, binary

A microbiologist has been given a set of $100$ blood vials. Exact one of those $100$ vials is positive to a concrete disease X. The microbiologist desires to send only $7$ vials for analysis. He can mix as many samples as he wants into $1$ vial. Which and how many samples should contain every to-be-sent-for-analysis vial so the microbiologist can determine which of $100$ vials contains the contagious blood?

**Caution:** All $7$ vials are supposed to be sent at once! (So binary search is not an option.)

***Tip:*** The binary representation of $100$ is
  $1\cdot64 + 1\cdot32 + 1\cdot4  
= 1\cdot2^6 + 1\cdot2^5 + 0\cdot2^4 + 0\cdot2^3 + 1\cdot2^2 + 0\cdot2^1 + 0\cdot2^0=\\  
= (1100100)_2$

Comment: Hint: Number the samples $0$ to $99$. Into vial $i$, put the blood samples whose ID number has a $1$ in the $i$-th binary position. (So for example Vial $1$ has all the samples whose ID number as a $1$ in the first position, counting from the left, that is, all samples whose ID number is odd.)

Comment: can you give me an example of your thought please? sorry for that but my mathematical english is not quite good

Comment: I just wrote on paper your thought. I think it's not wright because then you will reduced the number of possible choises to 11 samples. Because vial 1 will contain samples from vials numbered 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 so if you get answered that vial number 1 contains the desease you cannot determine which exact one of 100 vials is contagious. Also we have 7 available vials. what about samples 80,81,82,...,100? Correct me if i don't get somenthing :)

Comment: Suppose we have $13$ samples, not $100$. Then each sample has a $4$-bit binary ID,  Into Vial $1$ we put a little of samples $1,3,5,7,11,13$ (these are the numbers with leftmost bit equal to $1$). Into Vial $2$ we put a little of samples $2,3,6,7,10,11$ (these have second bit from the left equal to $1$).  Into Vial $3$ we put a little from samples $4,5,7, 12,13$ and into Vial $4$ a little from $8,9,10,11,12,13$. Now find out which of these test positive. In the $i$-th position from the left, write $1$ if Vial $i$ tests positive, $0$ if it tests negative. The binary number we get (more)

Comment: (cont) tells us the ID number of the sample that has the disease $X$. (Added) It is the same for $100$ except we use $7$ bits, since every number from $0$ to $99$, indeed to $127$, has a $7$-bit binary representation.

Comment: You are absolutely wright! Thank you very much for your effort! :)

Comment: You are welcome. The same strategy with $8$ vials would take care of $256$ samples.

Comment: If you take the same puzzle but instead of exactly *one* vial being contaminated you have exactly *k* contaminated vials, then you have this puzzle over here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81737/wolves-and-sheep/

Answer (score 2):

Do you already know the answer to this question?  You really should indicate that if you do.

I presume the microbiologist determines the $7$-bit representation of the sample number, and sends all samples with the highest-order bit set into vial $1$, the second-highest-order bit into vial $2$, and so on, with those samples with the lowest-order bit set into vial $7$.  This presumes that each sample can be divided into at least $6$ parts that are sufficient for analysis.  (There are fewer than $2^7-1 = 127$ samples, so there are no samples that will be put into all $7$ vials.)

ETA: Let me elaborate on how to interpret the results.  Suppose that the results come back and vials $2$, $5$, and $6$ are positive for Disease X.  Then we write out the $7$-bit binary number with $1$ in the second, fifth, and sixth position: $0100110$.  That is equal to $2^5+2^2+2^1 = 32+4+2 = 38$, so the $38$th sample was the one positive for Disease X.

Comment: I don't know the answer of this riddle. I assume i should use the properties of prime numbers. After a bit of brainstorming i came to the idea that i have to divide 100 in such 7 mixes so every one of them excludes a number of samples. For example if to-be-sent vial number 1 contains blood of all 100 samples then to-be-sent vial number 2 has to exclude x ( maybe prime ) number of samples. Vial number 3 excludes another y number of samples left from vial number 2 and so on. Until we have excluded all 99 healthy samples.

Comment: Prime numbers?  No.  Use the binary representation of the sample number.  For instance, $13 = 2^3+2^2+2^0 = 8+4+1$, so the $7$-bit binary representation of $13$ is $0001101$.  You then put a bit of sample number $13$ into vials $4$, $5$, and $7$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Imagine for now that instead of 100, we had 128 blood vials to begin with [the number is easier as it its the 7th power of 2 [lets pretend the 28 last ones are empty]
2. Let us assume that we line them up and label them from left to right with tags 1 to 128, one tag per vial, tag label representing position.
3. Let us now take take 7 test vials and poor in blood from the 128 labelled ones in the following way:

Test vial 1: poor in blood from each of 1-64. [assume no blood poored from 65-128].

Test vial 2: poor in blood from 1-32, 65-96 inclussive.

Test vial 3: take blood from 1-16, 33-48, 65-80, 97-112.

Test vial 4: take blood from 1-8, 17-24, 33-40, 49-56, 65-72, 81-88, 97-106, 113-120.

Test vial 5: take blood from 1-4, 9-12, 17-20, 25-28, 33-36, 41-44, 49-52, 57-60, 65-68, 73-76, 81-84, 89-92, 97-100, 105-108, 113-116, 121-124.

Test vial 6: 1-2, 5-6, 9-10, 13-14, 17-18, 21-22, 25-26, 29-30, 33-34, 37-38, 41-42, 45-46, 49-50, 53-54, 57-58, 61-62, 65-66, 69-70, 73-74, 77-78, 81-82, 85-86, 89-90, 93-94, 97-98, 101-102, 105-106, 109-110, 113-114, 117-118, 121-122.

Test vial 7: all the odd numberred ones.

there are 7 test vials, each of which can either test positive or negative. In otherwords, we have 7 binary questions, which means that the number of different results can be 2^7 =128 different outcomes.

The above construction, allows the microbiologist, to infer each outcome, to a unique vial label.

For example:
If all 7 vials test positive, then the culprit will be number 1 [see if you can convince yourself that 1 is the only possible culprit.
See if you can convince yourself for the remaining 127 outcomes ;) ]

Now I would like to flip back this problem, back to the original poster and ask him or her this:

Can you find a construction, that can determine the culprit with less than 7 test vials? If so, then what is the minimum number of test vials required, in order to reveal the contaminated vial, out of a sample of 100 vials?

The answer is obvious.

But what if the contaminated sample was diluted to a degree which even if contamination was present, the vial will have tested negative because of inefficient equipment [which is the case in real life :) equipment is not 100% efficient at all molarities]

In this case, can we optimise the construction such that less than 7 test vails are required?

Hint:

despite the fact that:
2^x <100  for all x<7

One can find  a pair of p and q such that:

2^p . 3^q  > 100

where p+q < 7.

For example, what if we assume the following: a contaminated vial will still test negative if it so happens to be diluted to a molarity of less than 1 part in 200.

Many Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Number the samples 1-100.

Vial 1: All those with sample number of the form 1xxxxxx in binary

Vial 2: All those with sample number of the form x1xxxxx in binary

Vial 3: All those with sample number  of the form xx1xxxx in binary

etc.

Vial 7: All those with sample number of the form xxxxxx1 in binary